# Meteor Deployment at modulus.io

Tags: meteor, web-deployment, modulus.io

I never deployed a meteor app before. I never used such system of servos. I don't understand how it works. I always used plain shared hostings. Php etc.

My question is: How much traffic can a 396mb servo can handle?  I mean,  I know it depends on the app but is there any reference,  any clue for understanding what I may need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a typical 396MB servo can handle approximately 400 concurrent connections for a typical meteor app on the Modulus platform.

full disclosure: I am a Modulus employee.

Answer (score 1):

It varies greatly depending on your app, and there is no silver bullet here. The best you can do is to monitor and scale accordingly. Using [Kadira](https://kadira.io/) might help you a lot with that.

For what it's worth, I deployed a Meteor app on a 396MB Modulus servo a while ago, and it easily handled over a hundred or so simultaneous users even without Mongo oplog tailing.